# How to export a CSV file with a header using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, web-crawler, export-to-csv

I'm trying to figure out how to export the results of my script to a CSV file with python 2.7. The CSV file should contain two columns:

The first column should contain the URL results and I would like to give this column a name. The second column should  contain the `print` result `keyword found` or `keyword NOT found` (as seen after the first and second `print` function in my code). I would like to name the second column as well.

My code:

```
import urllib2
    
keyword = ['viewport']

with open('top1m-edited.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        strdomain = line.strip()
        if '.nl' in strdomain:
            try:
                req = urllib2.Request(strdomain.strip())
                response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
                html_content = response.read()

                for searchstring in keyword:
                    if searchstring.lower() in str(html_content).lower():
                        print (strdomain, keyword, 'keyword found')

                    else:
                        print (strdomain, 'keyword NOT found')

            except urllib2.HTTPError:
                print (strdomain,'HTTP ERROR')

            except urllib2.URLError:
                print (strdomain,'URL ERROR')

            except urllib2.socket.error:
                print (strdomain,'SOCKET ERROR')

            except urllib2.ssl.CertificateError:
                print (strdomain,'SSL Certificate ERROR')

f.close()
```

So what kind of code do I need to add in order to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `','.join()` method to convert a list into a string with a comma separator.

```
with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    # Write out your column headers
    f.write(','.join(['column1header', 'column2header']))

    # Replace your for loop with this to write to file instead of stdout
    for searchstring in keyword:
        if searchstring.lower() in str(html_content).lower():
            f.write(','.join([strdomain, 'keyword found']) + '\n')
        else:
            f.write(','.join([strdomain, 'keyword NOT found']) + '\n')
            print (strdomain, 'keyword NOT found')
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I added your code but this doenst work (see my edited post). Getting `IndentationError: unexpected unindent` error

Comment: Firstly, you don't need to duplicate the `with open() as f:` statement. You can put the logic in the second open statement starting with the for loop inside the first one. Also, the indentation occur might have occurred from copying code. What editor are you using? You may want to make spaces and indents visible. Sometimes mixing up 4 spaces with 1 tab causes the script not to run, but it is hard to see.

Comment: I'm using the latest pycharm. I will try your approach. Thx

Comment: Np, glad I could help!